# Permgen growing while deploying web applications on Jboss 6

Tags: jvm, jboss6.x, permgen

Am porting web applications which were earlier on Jboss 4.2.3 onto Jboss 6. There are about 12 web applications totally and out of which only 4 are deployed as of now.

These web applications are based on Axis2 1.5.5,spring 2.5,hibernate 3.2.5,OpenJPA 1.0, saxon 9.1.

The classloader isolation is set as follows

```
<class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
        <loader-repository>
            webapp:loader=webapp.war
            <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
        </loader-repository>
</class-loading>
```

I see that the PermGen has already reached 440MB and growing on Jboss 6 and I have set `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Can anyone provide me inputs in identifying the problem here.

Environment: JDK 1.6.0_26, Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Who says this is a problem?  12 apps is a lot to deploy on one JVM, and 440MB pf permgen doesn't sound hugely outrageous to handle that.

Comment: skaffman, thanks for your reply, the same apps take about 150-170MB of PermGen on JBoss 4.2.3 and the default setting of -XX:MaxPermSize=256m is quite good enough. But on Jboss 6 I have deployed only 5 out of the 12 apps and the PermGen is almost 3 times more. I also verified the number of classes loaded was about 25K on Jboss 4.2.3 and it's 60K on Jboss 6.

Comment: JBoss 6 is far more memory demanding than JBoss 4 was. This sounds about right.

Comment: At last I was able to put all the 12 applications. The server takes almost 10 min to start. Permgen has reached 1GB. Heap is about 1.8GB. My desktop runs in animation :). I have 4GB ram. By the way am on 64bit hardware/OS/JDK.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why JBoss 6 is more demanding on the perm gen memory side, i do not know. 
But the startup time might be improved when you disable annotation scanning (if not using that). It helped for our application.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem last week. The JBoss-6 Microcontainer tries to scan for Jboss specific annotations by loading the classes from all the JARs in the class-path on startup. This causes the PermGen bloating as it starts to load all the unwanted classes.

To reduce the amount of scanning, the Microcontainer provides another descriptor hook, by means of jboss-scanning.xml.
Add  this 'jboss-scanning.xml' to the WEB-INF inside WARs and  ass 'jboss-scanning.xml' to the META-INF inside EARs.

```
<scanning xmlns="urn:jboss:scanning:1.0">

    <!-- Purpose: Disable scanning for annotations in contained deployment. -->

</scanning>
```